# Rest parameters in a Typescript Declaration file

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, .d.ts

I'm using VSCode to parse my JS for types using Declaration file + JSDoc. This shouldn't matter, but maybe?

In my declaration I have

```
declare interface World {
  getEntities: function():Entity[],
}
```

However I want to call getEntities with variable number of arguments.

```
world.getEntities( 'zone', 'area' )
```

This will give me the expected error: `Expected 0 arguments, but got 2.`

Reading how other people implemented it, I should be doing:

```
declare interface World {
  getEntities: function(...a:any[]):Entity[],
}
```

However I'll get the error `',' expected.` in my .d.ts where the `:` is.

How does one actually declare a function with variable arguments? Is this a VSCode issue? Or a TS issue? Am I just doing it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I should just be doing

```
declare interface World {
  getEntities: function(...args):Entity[]
}
```

Which is not the same answer as the first [google result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12907038/typescript-declaration-file-for-function-with-variable-number-type-of-arguments).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about using `function` for but both of these forms should work:

```
declare interface World {
    getEntities(...a: any[]): Entity[];
}
```

or

```
declare interface World {
    getEntities: (...a: any[]) => Entity[];
}
```