# declaring return type for an arrow functions with dynamic parameters

Tags: typescript, interface, type-declaration

i have an arrow function with dynamic parameters like

```
let user_data: any = {
    parameters: ["user_name", "status"],
    validate: (user_name: string, status: boolean) => {
        if (user_name && status) {
            return true;
        }
        return false
    },
    user_name: "name-1",
    status: false
}

let parameter_values: any[] = [];
for (let key_name of user_data["parameters"]) {
    parameter_values.push(user_data[key_name])
}
let valid_user = user_data["validate"](...parameter_values)
```

same function with single parameter

```
let user_data: any = {
    parameters: ["status"],
    validate: (status: boolean) => {
        return status ?? false
    },
    user_name: "name-2",
    status: false
}

let parameter_values: any[] = [];
for (let key_name of user_data["parameters"]) {
    parameter_values.push(user_data[key_name])
}
let valid_user = user_data["validate"](...parameter_values)
```

and some times it can be

```
let user_data: any = {
    parameters: [],
    validate: () => {
        return true
    },
    user_name: "name-3"
}
```

now i have to declare return type for the function in the interface and whatever the input my return type must be boolean, my interface look like

```
export interface UserData {
    parameters: string[],
    validate: Function, //should be function with return type boolean
    user_name: string,
    status?: boolean,
    [k: string]: any
}
```

i have searched for this but i found return type only for static parameters like this

```
interface Example {
    foo: () => string;
    bar(): string;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeScript declaration file for function with variable number/type of arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12907038/typescript-declaration-file-for-function-with-variable-number-type-of-arguments)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a rest parameter in your interface declaration like this:

```
interface Foo {
    validate(...a_args: unknown[]): boolean;
}
```

This works for the following:

```
const foo1: Foo = {
    validate(){ return true; }
}

const foo2: Foo = {
    validate(a_status: boolean){ return a_status ?? false; }
}

const foo3: Foo = {
    validate(a_username: string, a_status: boolean){ return a_status && !!a_username; }
}
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/wOlgpN)

Comment: hi, thankyou for your answer it is working perfectly and i have one more doubt, if the key is optional is it correct way to declare optional key like this `validate?(...args:unknown[]):boolean`

Comment: @saiteja Hey, that is correct, yep. With this, `validate` will be treated as an optional property just like if you write  `{ name?: string; }`